# AV on GET request by TIdHTTP

Tags: c++, multithreading, access-violation, indy10, c++builder-6

`TIdHTTP::Get` throws exception `EAccessViolation` when trying to send `GET` request. Actually, I need to retrieve web page html-content. I decided to use `TIdHTML` + SSL socket handlers (that's because I need to access https).
Here is my code:

```
int Foo::bar()
{
    try
    {
        std::auto_ptr<TIdHTTP> idHttp(new TIdHTTP(NULL));
        std::auto_ptr<TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL>
                sslSock(new TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL(NULL));

        idHttp->HandleRedirects = true;        
        idHttp->IOHandler       = sslSock.get();

        AnsiString reply;
        // right there exception is being thrown
        reply = idHttp->Get("https://www.yandex.com/");

        ShowMessage(reply);
    }
    catch(EIdException & e)
    {            
        ShowMessage(e.Message);
    }
    catch(Exception & e)
    {
        ShowMessage(e.Message);
    }
}
```

Actually, there's the thing: my app is *very* multi-threaded. All this stuff is executed in a *non-main* thread. According to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15977505/access-violation-with-tidhttp-running-on-many-threads-at-same-time), probably, it's about `IsMultiThread` variable (but I have already set it to `true`), so I don't know why `TIdHTTP` every time tries to `Read memory at 00000008`.

Comment: Please show the complete exception message. An AV near address 00000000 means a NULL pointer is being accessed. Which exact version of Indy 10 are you using?

Comment: `idHttp->Version` said "10.6.2.0"

Comment: There is nothing in the code shown that is affected by threads or `IsMultiThread` (unless you assign the `ConnectTimeout` property, then `TIdHTTP` uses a thread to implement that timeout). You will have to step into the source code of `TIdHTTP.Get()` with the debugger to find out what is causing the AV. It does not happen in later Delphi/C++Builder versions, so it might be something specific to BCB6 that needs fixing. Indy does have some C++-specific workarounds during compiling. BTW, did you compile Indy for C++ with `BCB` defined, or are you using Malcolm Smith's precompiled binaries?

Comment: An instance of `Foo` class is created in a separate thread. That's why I linked "multithreading". Actually, I use Malcolm Smith's binaries. Is that a problem?

Comment: Probably not. Malcolm and I work together on Indy C++ issues, and he wrote the C++ compile scripts for Indy. So I would have to suspect a BCB6 issue before an Indy issue. But since you are using precompiled binaries, you can't step into Indy's source code to see what is actually happening.